# What exactly does .(data_type) method called/do?

Tags: go

I came a cross a piece of code that used `.(string)` method. Not knowing what this is called I had difficulties searching for it.

Here is my try to understand it:

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "reflect"

func main(){
    var b interface{}
    b = "silly"

    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(b.(string))) // we know that b 
                                            // is a string                     
                                            // at compile time

    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(b))          // we do not

}
```

Result:

```
string
string
```

However, I think that `reflect.TypeOf` takes place at run time, while `.(string)` would tell the compiler that `b` is indeed a string, and this could be used to tell the compiler that a variable is of certain type. Is my understanding right?

[goplayground](https://play.golang.org/p/eTz3HXH3fc)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`b.(string)` is called a **[type assertion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions)**. As written in **[Effective Go](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#interface_conversions)**:

> A type assertion takes an interface value and extracts from it a value of the specified explicit type.

So, yes, the value you get from a type assertion is not an interface value, but is of the explicit type. You can also test if the type assertion was successful by adding an untyped boolean value:

```
s, ok := b.(string) // s is of type string
if !ok {
    // b did not contain a value of type string!
}
```

**Edit:**

To explain further to clear out any possible misunderstanding:

A type assertion doesn't *"tell Go that b is a string"* as you suggested. What it does is that it will, in run time, try to extract a string from `b`, and panic if `b` contains some other type (unless assigning the optional bool value).

The value that you get from the assertion will indeed be of type `string`, allowing you to do things like slicing (you cannot slice an interface value) or checking its `len`.

Comment: A much better example is to use it with a switch.  Go uses type asserts with switches everywhere, so that you can pass around things of unknown type, yet not find yourself going down a branch dealing with an improperly cast object.

Comment: @Rob if you feel that a good example is missing feel free to add it in your answer.

Answer (score 2):

The previous answer is correct.  But I submit this as more like what happens in practice.  The .(type) syntax is usually used with type names in the cases of a switch.  In this example, I (integer expr), B (bool expr), and Bop (binary op) are type names.

```
func commute (e Expr) (r Expr, d bool) {
    switch exp:= e.(type) {
        case I: r,d = exp,false
        case B: r,d = exp,false
        case Bop: r,d = Bop{exp.op, exp.right, exp.left},true
        default: r,d = e,false
    }
    return
}
```

This isn't unsafe like a C cast, because inside the case statement you are guaranteed to have the matching type.  I see this quite a bit when reading a channel, where the type of the channel is an interface that all the cases implement.

Comment: [Type switches](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_switches) are a separate concept and construct from [type assertions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions). It's just an arbitrary (but nice) design choice to make the former use a `x.(type)` syntax rather than (say) `typeof(x)`.

Comment: I'll be honest, as examples go, this is rather confusing :) I liked better the other answer as it makes it clear what a type assertion is.  Maybe it's just the formatting that's confusing or the purpose of the code snippet - or (much more likely) just me :)